# Same output for a list in django

Tags: python, list

I wrote the following code :

```
d={}
dlist=[]

for x in list1:
    d['name']=x.name
    d['age']=x.age
for y in list2:
    d['gender']=y.gender
    dlist.append(d)
```

list 1 and list 2 contains some objects.
I pass the dlist to a table in order to display the content. Normally i have 4 different results but when displayed only the last one is displayed 4 times.
What is the problem?

Comment: try losing the indent on the append line

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to define `d` inside the loop on each step of iteration. Also, you may want to use zip in order to loop list1 and list2 in one loop:

```
dlist=[]
for x, y in zip(list1, list2):
    d={'name': x.name, 'age': x.age, 'gender': y.gender}
    dlist.append(d)
```

or, a one-liner:

```
dlist = [{'name': x.name, 'age': x.age, 'gender': y.gender} for x, y in zip(list1, list2)]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
dlist.append(d)
```

The problem is that you keep appending the *one* dictionary `d` to the the list. Even if you change the values and append it then, all that’s actually added to the list is a reference to the dictionary. And all references to the dictionary are the same as you only create a dictionary once, and just change its contents later on.

So you need to create a new dictionary whenever you want to append a new object to the list.